# Ignore vim java warnings

Tags: java, vim, macvim

I am using the janus distro of vim and started to editing some java files..
I have some errors on the left, saying that it can't locate my packages..

[image]

Where are those errors are coming from? and how do I ignore those errors?

Comment: 1. Janus is not a Vim distro. 2. Janus is a worthless pile of crap designed to make Vim beginners believe that they can start to use Vim without effort. 3. You should delete Janus. 4. If you insist on using Janus, see if you have a plugin called Syntastic and, if positive, read `:help syntastic` where you can find how to disable it for certain filetypes. 5. You should delete Janus anyway.

Comment: @romainl you tell what I thought. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I took a look (not so deeply) the Janus project, it used syntastic as syntax checker.

Java checker of Syntastic  has a command `:SyntasticJavacEditClasspath`, which allows you to add your classpaths. Also it supports load cp from maven repositories. just take a look the https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/java/javac.vim

hope it helps.